# How do I remove white space margins from grid.table window?

Tags: r

If I use `grid.table` for a small table, the default window is too large, resulting in large white space margins on the top, bottom, left and right. Here is an example:

```
grid.table(data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
```

[image]

When I save the above window as a png, and then copy it into Word, I end up having to spend time cropping it. I'd rather the initial window just have 1/4-inch padding around the table so I don't have to crop anything and can just copy and paste. However, I can't find any way of determining the table's dimensions, which would allow me to pre-emptively size the window (and I don't want to "play" with the window dimensions because that's as inefficient as cropping and I produce several small tables of different sizes). I also tried to use `grid.arrange`, but the only parameter I could set was "heights" and all that did was slide the table up (by shrinking the top margin) while keeping the window the same size. I'll take any solution on this one- it doesn't have to be a png.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have for now is to open a png device, manually set/estimate the height and width, execute the grid, and turn the device off.

```
png(filename=myFilename, 
    height = (22/myRes)*(nrow(myTable)+1),
    width = (22/myRes)*(ncol(myTable))*4,
    units = "in", res = 72)
grid.table(myTable)
dev.off()

# "22" font height determined by trial and error, worked for 2 to 8 rows but drifting is observed
# "+1" accounts for an additional row for the column labels
# "*4" each column estimated to be four times its height
# "72" dpi
```

Since the row heights are consistent, my png was pretty tight on the top and bottom margins. However, the left and right margins varied between 1/4- and 1/2-inch, and since the number of columns I was dealing with was constant, I don't know how bad it could get with more/less columns.